# How to concatenate a var with using php

Tags: php, variables, concatenation, nodes

Hi I have this code `$node->field['un']` but that sentence is repeated a lot of times, I want to do this:

```
$varstring="value";
node->$varstring['un'];
```

But I cant do it, how cant i replace `field` for my var `$varstring` i want to replace `field` with `$varstring`.

Could you please help me?.

Comment: `$node->{$varstring}['un'];`

Comment: You could just create a reference `$var &= $node->field` then access `$var['un']`.  Seems like a cleaner solution to me.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using PHP 7 then `$node->$varstring['un']` would work as you expect. Prior to PHP 7 you need to use braces to force the evaluation order like this `$node->{$varstring}['un']` otherwise, in PHP 5, it is read as `$node->{$varstring['un']}` which assumes `$varstring` is an array, and tries to find a key named `'un'` in that array to hand the result value back to `$node`.

Here's an example and differences between PHP 5 and PHP 7.

## Wrong Way in PHP 5

```
$node = new stdClass;
$node->a = ["un" => "a.un"];
$node->b = ["un" => "b.un"];
$node->c = ["un" => "c.un"];

$varstring = "a";

var_dump($node->$varstring['un']);
```

In PHP 5 you get

```
PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'un' in /tmp/test.php code on line 9

Warning: Illegal string offset 'un' in /tmp/test.php code on line 9
array(1) {
  ["un"]=>
  string(4) "a.un"
}
```

## Right Way in both PHP 5 and PHP 7

```
$node = new stdClass;
$node->a = ["un" => "a.un"];
$node->b = ["un" => "b.un"];
$node->c = ["un" => "c.un"];

$varstring = "a";

var_dump($node->{$varstring}['un']);
```

In PHP 5 or 7 you get

```
string(4) "a.un"
```

## Right Way in PHP 7 only

```
$node = new stdClass;
$node->a = ["un" => "a.un"];
$node->b = ["un" => "b.un"];
$node->c = ["un" => "c.un"];

$varstring = "a";

var_dump($node->$varstring['un']);
```

In PHP 7 you get

```
string(4) "a.un"
```

## Prepare for PHP 7

If you use the braces it remains backwards compatible with PHP 5 and still continues to work the same in PHP 7 (forwards compatible). So you *should* definitely prep any existing code for PHP 7 as PHP 5 is going to be on its way out the door not long from now (*maybe in a year or two*).

The syntax is called [Uniform Variable Syntax](https://github.com/tpunt/PHP7-Reference#uniform-variable-syntax) in case you want to read about it some more. Simply put, the easiest way to remember this is that in PHP 7 *every* variable expression is read **from left-to-right** whereas in PHP 5 you had some inconsistencies like in your example here (*some parts left-to-right other parts right-to-left*).